# Search for PHP function which read array values

Tags: php, arrays, string

I try to create instead of the if conditions a function which read all values and positions of an array and call then a function. I check the documentation but cant find a solution. Is there any php function which could I take here?

```
function one() {
    echo '#btn1 {';
        echo 'animation-name:example;';
        echo 'animation-duration:1s;';
        echo 'animation-delay:0.5s;';
    echo '}';       
}

function two() {
    echo '#btn2 {';
        echo 'animation-name:example;';
        echo 'animation-duration:1s;';
        echo 'animation-delay:0.5s;';
    echo '}';       
}

$code = 12;
$arr1 = str_split($code);

if ($arr1[0] == 1) {
    one();
}
if ($arr1[0] == 2) {
    two();
}
if ($arr1[1] == 1) {
    one();
}
if ($arr1[1] == 2) {
    two();
}
if ($arr1[2] == 1)....
// Continues like this for about 36 times
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: Something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: I want to safe code. Thats only a piece of my code and of my if conditions, there are 36 :D

Comment: Instead of proving every condition you might wanto to have a look at [bitmasks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function one() {
    echo '#btn1 {';

        echo 'animation-name:example;';
        echo 'animation-duration:1s;';
        echo 'animation-delay:0.5s;';
    echo '}';       
}
function two() {
    echo '#btn2 {';

        echo 'animation-name:example;';
        echo 'animation-duration:1s;';
        echo 'animation-delay:0.5s;';
    echo '}';       
}

$code = 12;
$arr1 = str_split($code);

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    switch($value) {
        case 1:
            one();
        break;
        case 2:
            two();
        break;
    }
}
```

Everything made a bit more compact

```
$code = 12;
$arr1 = str_split($code);
$css = '';
foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    $css .= '#btn' . $value . ' {';
    $css .= '    animation-name:example;';
    $css .= '    animation-duration:1s;';
    $css .= '    animation-delay:0.5s;';
    $css .= '}'; 
}

echo $css; // output variable
```

Comment: Thank you buddy!! One last question: If `$code = 34267` and I have seven buttons is it with this way possible that first the third button then the fourth button, then the second button and so forth becomes animated? Thank you for this post ;)

Comment: @klamertd, For as far as I understand what you just said **Yes** :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$map = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'tri', 4 => 'four');

function one(){
    echo 'I am inside function one()';
}

function two(){
    echo 'I am inside function two()';
}

function tri(){
    echo 'I am inside function tri()';
}

$str = '1324';
for($i = 0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
    echo 'Number: ' . $str[$i] . '<br>';
    echo 'Function: ' . $map[$str[$i]] . '<br>';
    echo 'CALLING IT: ';
    $map[$str[$i]]();
    echo '<br> ---------------------------- <br>';
}
```

Note that if the function does not exist (`four()` in this case), it causes an error.

**Output:**

```
Number: 1
Function: one
CALLING IT: I am inside function one()
---------------------------- 
Number: 3
Function: tri
CALLING IT: I am inside function tri()
---------------------------- 
Number: 2
Function: two
CALLING IT: I am inside function two()
---------------------------- 
Number: 4
Function: four
CALLING IT: E_ERROR : type 1 -- Call to undefined function four() -- at line 21
```